# update json data into db

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

Alright... this seems complicated for me..

I don't know if it is.

**filename: add_types.js**

I have some data, which i create into mysql db (is for a back-end system). 
through jquery/ json. It work fine.

```
            var last_id = data.last_id;
        var fck_editor = data.fck_editor;

        var new_data = '<div id="input_highlight'+last_id+'"><strong style="font-size:14px;">Overskrift:</strong> <br />';
        new_data += '<input type="text" name="overskrift[]" /><br />';
        new_data += '<input type="hidden" name="tekst_id[]" value="'+data.last_id+'" />';
        new_data +=  fck_editor;
        new_data += '<a href="javascript:;" onclick="remove_rejse('+last_id+');" title="Slet"><img src="/gfx/admin/icons/delete.png" alt="" />Slet</a>';
        new_data += '</div><div id="loader'+last_id+'"></div><br />';                       

        $(div_id).append(new_data);
```

Now I just need to update it (in the same file where it gets outputed)

**rejser.php**
my data goes out here in a div

```
<div id="add_here" class="add_here_bg"></div>
```

I want the ouput from add_types.js to be updated in db when i submit another form in the rejser.php file.

pls inform me, if my question is understandable.

Comment: So, basically, the string data in `new_data` is supposed to be stored somewhere in a database field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular jQuery AJAX-request, which submits the contents of your div to a server-side script:

```
var content = $('#add_here').html();
$.get(url_of_script, content);
```

And then have the script add it to the DB. Are you familiar with using PHP/MySQL to do this?

If you want to update this stuff when a form is submitted, try attaching an event listener to the onSubmit event of the form.

Edit:

So, first add the onSubmit attribute to your form:

```
<form onSubmit="return formSubmit(event);">
```

Now, you'll have to define this function somewhere - really doesn't matter where you do it, though the `<head>` section of your page is recommended. External file is, of course, also possible.

```
function formSubmit(event) {
    var content = $('#add_here').html();

    // this callback will make sure the form is submitted after having completed the other request
    var callback = function() { event.target.submit() };
    $.get(url_of_script, content, callback);

    // Now, cancel the default event, the callback will take care of the submit afterwards
    event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Haven't tested it, but something like this is supposed to work. Let me know if you need some more help.

Comment: hmm, I'm not sure that i understand.. 


The script you postet should be pastet above the div.. or am i totally on the wrong way ? :-/
<script>
var content = $('#add_here').html();
$.get('/js/admin/add_types.js/', content);
</script>

<div id="add_here" class="add_here_bg"></div>

Comment: No, that won't work. If I understand you correctly, you need the data to be sent when a specific form on the page is submitted. This means you will need to attach a function to the onSubmit event (`<form onSubmit='return formSubmit(event);'>`, which will do this stuff for you before allowing the form to be sent. Enough info, or do you need a code example? Also, please try to be a little clearer on your intentions, please. Thanks ;-)

Comment: ah i see... 
Yes, you have understand it correctly. its just me.. :-/ 

I would be grateful if you could show me some code example!

Comment: hm... how do i take the ( overskrift[] ) from the outputed js... 

 $.get('js/admin/add_types.js', overskrift:overskrift, callback);

?

Comment: Excuse me, overskrift? Where does that come from?

Comment: ohh sorry.. from new_data

new_data += '<input type="text" name="overskrift[]" /><br />';

Comment: Hmm.. I'm afraid I've lost you. Do you want to get the values of that section? Please edit your post so that it contains a detailed description of what you want to do - it might allow me to be of better assistance.